# Viewing user responses from slack to errbot

Tags: slack-api, chatbot, errbot, chatops

I'm very new to bots. I'd like to develop a quick/simple test that makes it possible for a bot (errbot) to write a message to slack, then view responses back to the bot from users on slack.

How do I go about achieving this? Do I need to write a plugin for this?

Apologies if my question is too general/ambiguous -- I haven't come across an example that clearly explains this.

Comment: I've answered my own question. I do need to develop a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to program a bot a way or another, Errbot is just a framework that help you do that (concentrate on messages/responses) through plugins and not on the technicalities of the services it is connected to (Slack or any other).